# Remap Fedora 23 Keys under the i3 window manager

Tags: fedora, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout

I have read that `xmodmap` has been overridden by `xkb` since `Fedora 23`. I am using `i3`.

xkb seems really overwhelming when all I want to do is swap the windows key and alt key.

From `xev` the outputs are:

**Windows Key**

```
keycode 133 (keysym 0xffeb, Super_L)
```

**Alt Key**

```
keycode 64 (keysym 0xffe9, Alt_L)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out how to do achieve this finally using `setxkbmap`.

`setxkbmap -model thinkpad60 -layout us -variant int -option altwin:swap_alt_win`

You can find the premapped options in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev.lst`

You will need to add this to your startup file because the command only last as long as the session you execute it in.